# servlet mapping

Tags: servlets

I have created Sample.java servlet, it is in src folder.

and created HTML page in pages directory i.e, pages/First.html

Now I need to provide in servlet mapping as pages/Sample that I am not getting why pages directory name should mention in servlet url mapping.

As it is in root folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should never put any class in the root package.

Once you have put your Sample class in a package (example: `com.foo.andy.sample`), you need to declare the servet in the web.xml of your web application, and declare one (at least) mapping for this servlet.

You might follow [this tutorial](http://www.servletworld.com/servlet-tutorials/simple-servlet-example.html) to know how to do it.

You need these lines in the web.xml:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>SampleServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.foo.andy.sample.Sample</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>SampleServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/pages/Sample</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

And your servlet will be accessible at .../yourWebApp/pages/Sample

Answer (score 0):

We need servlet mapping to ensure that which servlet is going invoked at which type of url request . To do so you need to write `web.xml` file.
lets assume your class located at `com.example` package.

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>SampleServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.example.Sample</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>SampleServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/Sample</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

when you complete this code put the url (/Sample) at your `<form action="/Sample">` in HTML page.
make sure you should not put class in root directory.