# Mapping a specific servlet to be the default servlet in Tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, url-pattern

I am trying to implement a servlet that gets raw requests, and decide either to process them, or forward them to another backend server. It is similar to a load-balancer, where a received request is forwarded to one of the (in my case 2) destinations. One of the destination is remote (on another host). Furthermore, the requests could come to the root (http://mycompany.com/).

Since I want to get raw requests, I implemented my own servlet (subclassing `HttpServlet`), and that works great. My servlet looks like:

```
public class MyProxyServlet extends HttpServlet {
    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
        processOrForward(req, resp);
    }
    // also doGet(), doHead(), ...
}
```

Since the service I want to process may send requests to the root, I would like to map my servlet to be the default servlet, thereby receiving any request that does not have an explicit servlet mapping. Assume my servlet's name is "myservlet", and is running along side of another servlet "foo", I expect all requests in the form of http://mycompany.com/foo/... to be delivered to foo, and everything else (e.g., /, /bar/..., /myservlet/...) to "myservlet". Looking at earlier posts (eg., root mapping [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4177047/how-to-set-up-the-root-servlet-in-tomcat-6) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7159902/servlet-mapping), or url rewriting [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10427347/tomcat-url-mapping-individual-servlet-to-root-level)), I thought I figured it out, but it does not work.

Here is my *web.xml*:

```
<web-app>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>ProxyServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.mycompany.MyProxyServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>ProxyServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

In the above *web.xml*, for url-pattern I tried

```
"/" and "/*" and empty (i.e., <url-pattern></url-pattern>), all behave the same -->
    Requests to root (/)goes to tomcat's default servlet
    Requests to /myservlet/... are handled by "myservlet"
    Requests to /fubar/... are always 404
```

Is there a way of turning my servlet to be the default. I.e., any request that does not map specifically to a servlet comes to mine (it is even acceptable to receive all requests, since I can deploy this servlet in its own container). In case it matters, I am using Tomcat 7.0.30 on Ubuntu 12.10.

Comment: I think my question is the same as [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/800725/configure-web-xml-tomcat-5-for-one-servlet-to-handle-all-incoming-requests) (or the answer to this question will resolve the issue I am having)

Comment: If I understand you proper, then you are talking about how setup a fallback web-application in Tomcat. If so, then fiddling with web.xml (of yet another webapp) will not help. Instead you should look into Tomcat's documentation how to archive this, i.e. you must change Tomcat's configuration instead.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

This should be useful to you.

From the [**Java™ Servlet Specification Version 3.1 (JSR 340)**](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/servlet-3_1-fr-eval-spec/index.html)

> ### Chapter 12. Mapping Requests to Servlets
>
> #### 12.2 Specification of Mappings
>
> In the Web application deployment descriptor, the following syntax is used to define mappings:
>
> - A string beginning with a `/` character and ending with a `/*` suffix is used for
>     **path mapping**.
> - A string beginning with a `*.` prefix is used as an **extension mapping**.
> - The empty string `("")` is a **special URL pattern that exactly maps to the
>     application's context root**, i.e., requests of the form `http://host:port/<contextroot>/`.
>     In this case the path info is `/` and the servlet path and context path is
>     empty string `("")`.
> - A string containing only the `/` character indicates the **"default" servlet** of the
>     application. In this case the servlet path is the request URI minus the context path
>     and the path info is null.
> - All other strings are used for **exact matches** only.

As an addition, read this nice explanation with short examples from the book [Head First Servlets & JSP: Passing the Sun Certified Web Component Developer Exam (2nd edition)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596516681) (quote):

> The THREE types of `<url-pattern>` elements
>
> #### 1) EXACT match
>
> *Example:*
>   `<url-pattern>/Beer/SelectBeer.do</url-pattern>`
>
> - MUST begin with a slash (`/`).
> - Can have an extension (like .do), but it’s not required.
>
> #### 2) DIRECTORY match
>
> *Example:*
>   `<url-pattern>/Beer/*</url-pattern>`
>
> - MUST begin with a slash (`/`).
> - Always ends with a slash/asterisk (`/*`).
>
> #### 3) EXTENSION match
>
> *Example:*
>   `<url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>`
>
> - MUST begin with an asterisk (`*`) (NEVER with a slash).
> - After the asterisk, it MUST have a dot extension (.do, .jsp, etc.).

**IMPORTANT NOTE:**
The URL patterns represent *logical / virtual structure*, i.e. **the patterns (paths) specified does not need to exist physically**.

---

**UPDATE**

If you want, as you say in your comment,

> I want host:port to hit my servlet, not the default tomcat servlet

then see the solution here:
[How do I make my web application be the Tomcat default application](http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/HowTo#How_do_I_make_my_web_application_be_the_Tomcat_default_application.3F)

In other words, what you want is a path **without application context**, which implies the application context of the Tomcat default application.

Quote from the above link:

> In a standard Tomcat installation, you will notice that under the same
>   directory (CATALINA_BASE)/webapps/, there is a directory called **ROOT**
>   (the capitals are important, even under Windows). **That is the
>   residence of the current Tomcat default application, the one that is
>   called right now when a user calls up
>   `http://myhost.company.com[:port]`**. The trick is to put your
>   application in its place.

Comment: Thank you for your time. I did read this before I posted my request. However, my problem persists. Simply put, I want http://host:port/ to hit my servlet, not the default tomcat servlet. But as of this writing, when I do this, it always returns the webapps/ROOT/index.html, which is returned by org.apache.catalina.servlets.DefaultServlet, not MyProxyServlet I am deploying.

Comment: @VirtuallyReal OK, I've just made a quick test by implementing a custom _default servlet_. I made a simple _Servlet_ that just prints out a message "Default Servlet", mapped it in _web.xml_ to `/`. And the result is, that whenever a request is sent with the path that is not configured in _web.xml_, my _default servlet_ is triggered. So it works.

Comment: Thanks again. Simply doing <url-pattern>/</url-pattern> in my own web.xml did not work. However, dropping my webapp into the ROOT directory did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure did I understood what you want but probably intercept 404 is what you want to do, then redirect where you want.

I've came here to forum because I have strange problem with tomcat 7, mine is doing just what you want ;)

This is only one way how I can have root, EMPTY

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Default</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern></url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

That way : anything is redirected to this servlet, including images, etc, for example, I open another page, this show this one, root, then I can see in log 4 more request to same page, 3 for css and one for image.

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Default</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```