# ServletRegistration url mapping conflict with Spring DispatcherServlet

Tags: java, servlets, spring-mvc, servlet-3.0

I followed [this example](http://rockhoppertech.com/blog/spring-mvc-configuration-without-xml/) to configure my DispatcherServlet through java with Spring's `WebApplicationInitializer` --> `javax.servlet.ServletContainerInitializer`:

```
@Override
public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
    AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext mvcContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
    mvcContext.register(MyConfiguration.class);

    ServletRegistration.Dynamic appServlet = servletContext.addServlet("appServlet", new DispatcherServlet(mvcContext));
    appServlet.setLoadOnStartup(1);

    Set<String> mappingConflicts = appServlet.addMapping("/");
    if (!mappingConflicts.isEmpty()) {
        for (String s : mappingConflicts) {
            LOGGER.error("Servlet URL mapping conflict: {}", s);
        }
        throw new IllegalStateException("'appServlet' cannot be mapped to '/'");
    }
}
```

When I start-up Tomcat, I get the above `IllegalStateException` because [apparently there is already a Servlet](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRegistration.html#addMapping%28java.lang.String...%29) mapped to `/` and I can only assume that is Tomcat's default Servlet. If I ignore the mappingConflicts, my `DispatcherServlet` isn't mapped to anything.

Is there any way to override this default servlet mapping with my own or am I stuck mapping my `DispatcherServlet` to `/*`?

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14223150/mapping-a-specific-servlet-to-be-the-default-servlet-in-tomcat) provides a solution by changing where your application is deployed in the Catalina webapps folder, but I was hoping for something less intrusive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So turns out you can map `DispatcherServlet` or any other Servlet on `/` through Java (as opposed to xml where you could always do this), but only on Tomcat versions > 7.0.14, I was on 7.0.12.

See [this Bugzilla issue](https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=51278) for discussion.