# Mapping subdirectory with html files to JSP servlet

Tags: html, jsp, tomcat, servlets, mapping

I understand that I can map HTML files such that the JSP engine treats files with .html extensions the same as they do for .jsp files.  However, what I wish to do is more precise than that.  I want my JSP engine, Tomcat 5.5, to treat **only** those HTML files in a specific subdirectory, SecAuth, as JSP files.

I added the following in Tomcat's web.xml file and it did not work (in fact, an error ensued):

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>jsp</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>SecAuth/*.html</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Is it clear what I'm trying to accomplish?  Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Also maybe these links will help you: [.html pages as .jsp pages](http://tomcat.10.x6.nabble.com/html-pages-as-jsp-pages-td2144137.html) and [How to map non-jsp URL to a JSP?](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/tomcat-users/200107.mbox/%3CPine.BSF.4.21.0107271807540.7976-100000@localhost%3E)

Comment: btw You are not using the valid url patterns. Read here about mapping rules: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14225540/814702

Comment: Thank you.  Both links were supremely useful.  I changed it to /SecAuth/* to conform to standards.  I think that might do the trick.  Thank you for your help.  If you can just summarize what you wrote in the answer below, I'll give you a check.  Thanks again.