# Servlet Real Path

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, path

I am running a webapp under the directory blog. (e.g. www.example.com/blog).

I would like to get the real filesystem path of a request.

> e.g. www.example.com/blog/test-file.html ->
>   /usr/share/tomcat7/webapps/blog/test-file.html

I tried the following:

```
 public String realPath(HttpServletRequest request, ServletContext servletContext){
    String requestURI = request.getRequestURI();
    String realPath = servletContext.getRealPath(requestURI);
    return realPath;
}
```

However this returns

> /usr/share/tomcat7/webapps/blog/blog/test-file.html

What is the correct way to do this?

Comment: You're assuming that there is a real path for the file which does not need be true. It is possible that a web application container runs out of the `.jar` file without having a native file path.

Comment: @UwePlonus Thats irrelevant for the question I'm asking.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Short answer

To get the result you want, use [`HttpServletRequest#getServletPath()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getServletPath()) method as an argument to `getRealPath()` method.

This is the closest to what you want to accomplish (read the note below).

---

### Explanation

The reason you're getting such path (with double `blog`) is that you're using the result returned by the *getRequestURI()* method.

The *getRequestURI()* method returns the path starting with *application context*. In your case it will be:
`/blog/test-file.html`

What happens then, the *getRealPath()* method **appends** the string returned by *getRequestURI()* method to the real/physical path to the folder, where you application resides on the file system, which in your case is:
`/usr/share/tomcat7/webapps/blog/`

So the resulting path is:
`/usr/share/tomcat7/webapps/blog/blog/test-file.html`

That is the reason of your double `blog` issue.

---

### IMPORTANT NOTE

DISCLAIMER
*Maybe the OP is already aware of the information written below, but it is written for the sake of completeness.*

The real path you are trying to get **does not mean** you are getting, well, the **real path on your file system**. The [`url-pattern`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14225540/814702) configured in *web.xml* (or if you're using Servlet 3.0+ in the related annotation) is actually a **logical/virtual path**, which may or may not relate to the actual, physical path on a file system, i.e. **the patterns (paths) specified does not need to exist physically**.

Also quote from the [ServletContext.getRealPath(String)](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getRealPath(java.lang.String)) documentation (emphasis mine):

> Gets the real path corresponding to the given **virtual path**.

Comment: A confirmation for me :) . It was helpful