# web.xml and/or Filters to return welcome-file

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, web.xml, servlet-filters

I have a need to configure my Tomcat WAR for specific functionality, and not sure if it can all be accomplished via `web.xml`, or if I need to implement 1+ custom `Filter`s, or use some other type of hackery.

My app packages up as `myapp.war`. So when it's served from a local Tomcat instance, I can access it by going to `http://localhost:8080/myapp`.

Very simply, I have a `welcome-file` (`myapp.html`) that I want served if Tomcat receives the following requests:

- localhost:8080/myapp
- localhost:8080/myapp/
- localhost:8080/myapp/#
- localhost:8080/myapp/#<blah>

...where `<blah>` is any string/regex after the pound symbol (#).

So if the user goes to `http://localhost:8080/myapp`, then serve back `myapp.html`. If the user goes to `http://localhost:8080/myapp/#fjrifjri`, then guess what? Serve back `myapp.html`.

**But**, if the user goes to, say, `http://localhost:8080/myapp/fizz`, then I want normal `web.xml servlet-mapping` logic to kick in, and I want Tomcat to serve back whatever servlet is mapped to `/fizz`, etc.

Currently my `web.xml` looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
        http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
        version="2.5"
        xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee">
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>myapp.html</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: A JAX-RS resource would work. Probably lots of other ways too.

Comment: With your current configuration which cases work and which don't?

Comment: Thanks @MarcelStör (+1) - so are you saying that I alreadyy have this working? If so, how is this possible?!?

Comment: As an additional info about configuring URL mappings read [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14225540/814702).

Comment: Have you tested your current configuration?  It should already work as you want.

Comment: Thanks @Pino (+1) - when I get home I'll give it a try - can I ask why/how my config should already be working as desired? I never specified a pound symbol (#) anywhere...

Comment: The pound symbol specifies a target position in a given page (in this case the welcome page), if the target doesn't exist the page is displayed the same.

Comment: @Zac_Harvey :: Pino is correct :: The hash symbol won't change the requested page. In 'this' context the hash is simply a page anchor that doesn't exist so nothing happens.

Answer (score 11):

If you need to mess around with URLs you need to use  **servlet** and **servlet-mapping** tags:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    version="2.5"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee">
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>myapp.html</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>fizz</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>demo.fizz</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>fizz</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/fizz</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

where demo is your package and fizz your fizz.java
To modify url and files attached to the current url you need to use **servlet-mapping** tags where servlet called fizz is mapped to /fizz

This will allow you to change settings you are looking for.

Hope it helps...

Comment: Correct. As an additional information: an alternative to configuring servlet mappings in *web.xml* is to use [@WebServlet](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/annotation/WebServlet.html) annotation which is available since **Servlet version 3.0** (because the OP uses Apache Tomcat it must be [minimum Tomcat 7](http://tomcat.apache.org/whichversion.html)). Also the class names in Java [by convention](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconv-138413.html) should start with **upper** case letter (i.e. *Fizz.java*)

Comment: Thanks @Andrew_Dublin (+1) - can you give me the specific servlet mappings that will achieve what I'm looking for? Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

One way to accomplish this is using filters is as follows:

- Create a filter which is mapped to root `/` in `web.xml`as follows

  ```
  <filter>
    <filter-name>myWelcomeFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.test.MyWelcomeFilter</filter-class>
  </filter>
  ```
- and the filter mapping as follows

> ```
> <filter-mapping>
>   <filter-name>myWelcomeFilter</filter-name>
>   <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
> </filter-mapping>
> ```

- in the `doFilter()` method use the following code.

> ```
>  String pathInfo = request.getPathInfo();
>  if(null == pathInfo || pathInfo.startsWith("#") ){
>  response.sendRedirect("/myapp/myapp.html")
>  }else{
>   chain.doFilter(request, response);
>  }
> ```

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are trying to do is a default behavior.  I dont know why do you want to use a filter for this purpose. The url : `http://localhost:8080/myapp/#fjrifjri`
 or anything like that would land up in myapp.html if you use myapp.html as welcome file in web.xml. For opening specific servlet you can use the servlet tag as mentioned by Andrew.

Answer (score 1):

You can always write a javascript or jsp or servlet code in which you can judge the url and forward the request dependingly.

Answer (score 1):

I recently had the same problem as you have, at least in regards with the first two of your requirements. This is how I solved my problem:

My web.xml has this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>classpath:../myapp-context.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value></param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

and my application context (myapp-context.xml) has this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                       http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
                       http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
                       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
                       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

<context:component-scan base-package="com.toolkt.spring.mvc.app"/>

<mvc:annotation-driven />

<mvc:view-controller path="/" view-name="index" />

<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>
```

I put my index file (index.jsp) in TOMCAT_HOME/webapps/appctx/WEB-INF/jsp. I did not put welcome file list in web.xml as you can see above.

When I point the browser to 
    `http://localhost:8080/appctx` or `http://localhost:8080/appctx/` I land on the index file.

I used spring-framework-3.1.2 and is running the app in tomcat-7.0.27 on windows 7. (There are only two apps in my tomcat dev server - ROOT and appctx

I hope this will help. good luck.

Answer (score 1):

As others mentioned, you only have to sort out servlet mappings for `/myapp`; the mappings after `#` are, in fact redundant. The content after `#`, as well as the hash itself [are never sent to the server anyway](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/317760/how-to-get-url-hash-from-server-side).

Answer (score 1):

web.xml and servlets do not recognize '#' in URLs, that is purely a front-end construct, it tells the browser which link within the page you want to go to.  What you'll need to do is setup a mapping for the home page like so:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>WelcomePage</servlet-name>
    <jsp-file>/myapp.jsp</jsp-file>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>WelcomePage</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>   
</servlet-mapping>
```

and then do the rest of your servlet mappings as usual.

Answer (score 1):

Using filter -

```
<filter>
      <filter-name>MyFilter</filter-name>
      <filter-class>package.MyFilter</filter-class>          
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
      <filter-name>MyFilter</filter-name>
       <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern> 
</filter-mapping>

public class MyFilter implements javax.servlet.Filter {


 @Override
 public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain fc) throws   IOException, ServletException {
//this method calling before controller(servlet), every request

HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
String url = request.getRequestURL().toString();
if(url.lastIndexOf("/fizz") > -1) //fix this as it could be /fizz33 too
{


    RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("fizz.jsp"); //or whatever page..
    dispatcher.forward(req, res);
} else {
    fc.doFilter(req, res);
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

No need to create a filter. The simple solution is:

1. Edit web.xml

   ```
   <welcome-file-list>
       <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
   </welcome-file-list>
   ```
2. Rename myapp.html to index.html
3. Edit index.html and put a tag with `id="blah"` attribute somewhere in there. This is to
   make `localhost:8080/myapp/#<blah>` work.