# Error in getting php file from jqrid's property editurl

Tags: php, jakarta-ee, web, jqgrid

Below is the structure of my application.

```
myapp
 |- bin
 |- src
 |---- main
 |-------- java
 |-------- webapp
 |------------ resources
 |----------------- images
 |----------------- js
 |----------------- scritps
 |------------ WEB-INF
 |----------------- pages
 |--------------------- jsp files
 |----------------- web.xml and other application related xml files
```

I am using one jqgrid with its Form Editing feature. We have to set parameter `editurl:'some.php'` to make DB calls. As you can see I am keeping my jsps inside WEB-INF folder and we can not really access things inside WEB-INF folder from outside(i.e. browser).

Whatever value we set in `editurl` attribute, it gets appended to the URL. Like if I write `editurl:'some.php'`, then while submitting the data the URL will be changed into `http:localhost:port/myapp/some.php`. Which is not accessible in my case because its inside WEB-INF folder.

I also tried putting my php file outside WEB-INF folder and updated `edirurl` attribute accordingly but all in vain.

So my question is, how to access my php file with this configuration. I tried creating some dummy web application, kept things outside WEB-INF folder and its perfectly running fine.

Comment: Is your problem not solved?What happend?

Comment: read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14223150/mapping-a-specific-servlet-to-be-the-default-servlet-in-tomcat/14225540#14225540

Comment: @janina, Its solved. Actually, this post was posted before that post.