# Query on hitting specific servlet as default tomcat servlet

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets

I had been thru this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14223150/mapping-a-specific-servlet-to-be-the-default-servlet-in-tomcat) before i ask this question.

Generally when we browse `http://localhost:80/`  we see that  `../tomcat/conf/web.xml` (file1) is getting picked by servlet container but not `../tomcat/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/web.xml` (file2), and there is nothing in file2.

Now, I have access to enterprise application which is available as default tomcat servlet(DTS), When i say DTS, it mean, when i type `http://localhost:80/` I get the application page  as `http://localhost/ent-app/`

My question:

In the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14223150/mapping-a-specific-servlet-to-be-the-default-servlet-in-tomcat) , it says to place the required app in ROOT folder to make specific servlet as DTS. But in my case, ROOT folder's WEB-INF/web.xml has nothing related to ent-app, Please help me understand, How my ent-app is being picked by servlet container as DTS?

What are the things that i need to check in tomcat folder of my machine for this to understand?

Comment: ROOT folder has nothing related to my specific app. ROOT/WEB-INF/web.xml has this...   <display-name>Welcome to Tomcat</display-name>
  <description>
     Welcome to Tomcat
  </description>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to redirect `/` to `/ent-app`, then you need to configure that. There is no magic provided by the `ROOT` web application: you need to configure it yourself to perform the redirect.

You can either write your own servlet/filter that maps to `/*` and just redirects everything to `/ent-app`, or you can use something like [url-rewrite](http://tuckey.org/urlrewrite/) and simply configure it to your liking.

Comment: if there is no magic provided by ROOT, THEN why the above link talks about replacing my servlet in ROOT?

Comment: so that means, i need to check the web.xml in tomcat/webapps/ent-app/WEB-INF/web.xml to check how servlet mapping is done

Comment: Your `ent-app` application will only be sent requests whose URLs start with `/ent-app/`. That means if you request `/foo` then the request will go to some other application. Assuming that `/foo` doesn't map to any *other* web application, it will be sent to the `ROOT` application. Just write a simple redirector from the ROOT web application to the `/ent-app` application.

Comment: but why defaultservlet is pointed from tomcat/conf/web.xml ? This the web.xml that is directing what to do. So my question is, ideally this web.xml has to be in ROOT/WEB-INF folder.

Comment: `CATALINA_BASE/conf/web.xml` is the default `web.xml` for all web applications. You should pretty much never edit it. What you want is a servlet (or filter) in your `ROOT` webapp that performs a redirect. That's possible to do *without* a `WEB-INF/web.xml`, but more straightforward if you do. `CATALINA_BASE/conf/web.xml` should never be under consideration for editing.