# JSP doesn't open CSS, Images and JS

Tags: jsp, url, servlets, jstl, static-content

I'm trying to put CSS, JS and IMGs on my JSP, but doesn't work, it's strange because I use `c:url` and JSTL core.

I'm using JSP,  JSTL and Servlet, no frameworks.

[image: structure]

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" prefix="fmt" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>    
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>clientes atuantes</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="<c:url value="/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="<c:url value="/css/layout.css"/>">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="<c:url value="/bootstrap/js/jquery-1.12.0.js" />"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="<c:url value="/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js" />"></script>
    </head>
    <body>

        <main>
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="panel panel-default espacamentoExterno5">

                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <p><img src="<c:url value="/img/ativo.gif"/>" /> ativo</p>
                        <p><img src="<c:url value="/img/congelado.gif"/>" /> congelado</p>
                        <p><img src="<c:url value="/img/cancelado.gif"/>" /> cancelado</p>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </main>
    </body>
</html>
```

**`web.xml`:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
         xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
         xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" version="3.0">
    
  <display-name>PainelProduct</display-name>
  

</web-app>
```

Comment: are you phasing any error ? if yes then please post here.

Comment: Show the output of your code.

Comment: any error, only doesn't find images, css, js

Comment: check properly, whether you have make available proper jar(jstl) on classpath or not ?

Comment: may i know you img directory location into project-structure...?

Comment: yes, jstl jar is on classpath

Comment: my project structure 
webcontent
-web-inf
--jsp
---produtos.jsp
-css
--Css files
-img
--IMGS files
-js
--js files

Comment: /PainelIProduct/img/ativo.gif

Comment: @user3061516 You were asked how the link tag is rendered, not the image href.

Comment: @user3061516 good, now tell which server did you use and how it's deployed.

Comment: IDE: netbeans, Server: glassfish 4.1

Comment: @user3061516 Also post `web.xml`.

Comment: sorry, bootstrap href: /PainelProduct/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css // layout.css href: /PainelProduct/css/layout.css // jquery href: /PainelProduct/bootstrap/js/jquery-1.12.0.js // bootstrap js href: /PainelProduct/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js

Comment: I will editi topic to put web.xml

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
   xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
   xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" version="3.0">
    
  <display-name>PainelProduct</display-name>
  

</web-app>

Comment: I added on the topic too

Comment: What url did you use to access JSP page? And post mapping for all servlets or just tell if you use "/" in the url mapping.

Comment: url: http://localhost:8080/PainelProduct // servlet mapping: @WebServlet(urlPatterns="/") // dispatcher: RequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/jsp/incidente.jsp");

Comment: [⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35730121/573032)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The url pattern `"/"` has a special meaning to the web server. It's used for default servlet mapping which is capable of serving the static content. The static content is JS, CSS, images, html resources. Directing these files to your servlet is wrong, because it's not capable to serve the static content.

Change the servlet mapping to something `@WebServlet(urlPatterns="/incidente")`

and use url `localhost:8080/PainelProduct/incidente` to forward to jsp page.

Check this question to learn more about servlets and servlet mapping [Mapping a specific servlet to be the default servlet in Tomcat](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14223150/573032).

Comment: could I do more one question? how can I put "/incidente" like first page?

Comment: make this page to forward to this "/incedente", when you forward the url remains the same.

Answer (score 1):

I have encountered the same problem and have not resolved it for a long time. Then I realized that it was a problem from the path of the images.

Wrong path is like that;

> src>main>resources>images

**The order of files(path) should definitely be as follows.**

> src>main>webapp>resources>images

**and you should to call the function like that;**

```
<img src="<c:url value="/resources/img/logo.png"/>" alt=""/>
```