# Spring MVC app not recognizing bootstrap CSS

Tags: java, css, spring, twitter-bootstrap

Including the relevant files, I have tried so many different combinations of things but nothing seems to work. The app loads but the css does not. Any help appreciated

index. jsp

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Bootstrap 101 Template</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href='<c:url value="/resources/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css" />' />
</head>
<body>
<h1>Hello, world!</h1>

<ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu">
  <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Action</a></li>
  <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Another action</a></li>
  <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
  <li class="divider"></li>
  <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Separated link</a></li>
</ul>

<script src="<c:url value="resources/js/bootstrap.min.js"/>"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="startup.controller" />

    <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />
    <mvc:annotation-driven/>

    <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix">
            <value>/WEB-INF/pages/</value>
        </property>
        <property name="suffix">
            <value>.jsp</value>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

web.xml

```
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
          http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    version="2.5">

    <display-name>Web Application</display-name>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
</web-app>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to set DEBUG logging level and then you will see why ViewRelolver can't find css resource.

Comment: this is not the kind of answers the site is looking for, this is a comment at best and a poor one at that.

Answer (score 0):

Try without the "c:url" tag, but with simple "link, change the following line:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href='<c:url value="/resources/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css" />' />
```

to

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="resources/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css">
```

Notice that I have also removed the first "/", refer to this: [JSP doesn't open CSS, Images and JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35726851/jsp-doesnt-open-css-images-and-js)

Also make sure, that the path to the css file (resources/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css) is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Try using CDN links:

```
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Here you can find more information about above links: http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/